# Having issues with ad loading

Tags: android, admob

I have an error that appears as:

```
Failed to load ad: 2
```

The ads are not appearing and I am receiving this message. I am pretty sure my code is fine along with the formatting in the xml layout. Does this have something to do with the servers or failed connection? Will the ads still appear on google play?

Comment: check wheather adblock is disabled

Comment: I did I don't have it installed

Comment: @leonardo Please post your xml code where your ad is in and also your code to initialize the ad.